# Inconsistent behavior when assigning array to a property let

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, properties

Consider following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Let Dummy(v() As Integer)

End Property

Public Sub LetDummy(v() As Integer)

End Sub

Sub Foo()
    ReDim i(0 To 2) As Integer
    i(0) = 3
    i(1) = 45
    i(2) = 10

    Bar i ' internal error 51
End Sub

Sub Foo2()
    ReDim i(0 To 2) As Integer
    i(0) = 3
    i(1) = 45
    i(2) = 10

    Bar2 i ' no error
End Sub

Sub Foo3()
    ReDim i(0 To 2) As Integer
    i(0) = 3
    i(1) = 45
    i(2) = 10

    Dummy = i ' no error
End Sub

Sub Bar(j() As Integer)
    Dummy = j
End Sub

Sub Bar2(j() As Integer)
    LetDummy j
End Sub
```

When I run macro 'Foo' i get message 'internal error 51' but 'Foo2' and 'Foo3' runs fine. What's the reason for this behavior? Or is it simply a bug in VBA? How to fix this error?

Background: In my application I want to assign array provided as function argument to property of type array.

Comment: I can't explain why but would guess that a fixed size copy of the array is actually being passed to the property let procedure. The only real difference between your `Property Let` and your `LetDummy` sub is that property procedures always take their arguments `ByVal` and since you can't pass an array ByVal in VBA, it has to be getting a copy. Why it works if you call the property directly, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Wow, Excel actually crashed on me (the whole "Excel has stopped working" thing) trying to experiment with this.

Comment: @Rory - *property procedures always take their arguments `ByVal`* - Is that documented somewhere? I can see that the `VarPtr` on a property argument is different, so it's clearly a copy, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266197(v=vs.60).aspx) just says "ByRef is the default in Visual Basic"

Comment: @ThunderFrame it's in the language specification: "If the <value-param> of a <property-LHS-declaration> does not have a <parameter-mechanism> element or has a <parameter-mechanism> consisting of the keyword ByRef, it has the same meaning as if it instead had a <parameter-mechanism> element consisting of the keyword ByVal."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me since Error 51 says to contact MS if you get it.

If I create a local variable, assign it, then pass it along it seems to work.

Very hacky.

```
Option Explicit

Private ary() As Integer

Public Property Get Dummy() As Integer()
    Dummy = ary
End Property

Public Property Let Dummy(v() As Integer)
    Debug.Print "In Dummy" & UBound(v)
    ary = v

End Property

Public Sub LetDummy(v() As Integer)
    Debug.Print "In LetDummy" & UBound(v)
End Sub

Sub Foo()
    ReDim i(0 To 2) As Integer
    i(0) = 3
    i(1) = 45
    i(2) = 10

    Call Bar(i)  ' internal error 51
End Sub

Sub Foo2()
    ReDim i(0 To 2) As Integer
    i(0) = 3
    i(1) = 45
    i(2) = 10

    Bar2 i ' no error
End Sub

Sub Foo3()
    ReDim i(0 To 2) As Integer
    i(0) = 3
    i(1) = 45
    i(2) = 10

    Dummy = i ' no error
End Sub

Sub Bar(j() As Integer)
    Dim i() As Integer
    i = j

    Dummy = i

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim myary() As Integer
    myary = Dummy
    For x = 0 To 2
        Debug.Print myary(x)
    Next
End Sub

Sub Bar2(j() As Integer)
    LetDummy j
End Sub
```

Comment: @markovcd, so you chose to add a new variable and accept the little more hussle it brings along instead of simply declaring `Public Property Let Dummy(v As Variant)`?

Comment: Changing type to variant made cascade of errors in my code. Decided to go with this one. Upvoted your answer of course as it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite an interesting bug. While trying to reproduce it I came up with this:

```
Public Property Let Foo(ByRef values() As Long)
End Property

Public Sub Test()
    Dim values(0 To 1) As Long
    values(0) = 1
    values(1) = 2
    IllegalByRefArray values
End Sub

Private Sub IllegalByRefArray(ByRef values() As Long)
    Stop 'break here or crash Excel
    Foo = values
End Sub
```

Instead of run-time error 51, I got a hard crash. "Excel has stopped working", and poof, gone. Running 64-bit Excel 2010.

Running Excel with a Visual Studio debugger attached, I could see how the EXCEL.EXE process completely blows up on the `Foo = values` assignment:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF834E4B90 (ntdll.dll) in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000028: An invalid or unaligned stack was encountered during an unwind operation

So there's definitely something fishy going on. Thing is, a property that exposes an array is kind of a weird thing in the first place: *normally* you would *encapsulate* the array and expose an *indexed property*, i.e. something like this:

```
Private internal() As Long 'todo initialize

Public Property Let Foo(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As Long)
    internal(index) = value
End Property

Public Property Get Foo(ByVal index As Long) As Long
    Foo = internal(index)
End Property
```

Still, the language doesn't explicitly forbid exposing an array as a property... or does it?

This is a compile-time error, namely, ***can't assign to array***:

```
Public Property Let Foo(ByRef values() As Long)
End Property

Public Sub Test()
    Dim values(0 To 1) As Long
    values(0) = 1
    values(1) = 2
    Foo = values ' compile error / can't assign to array
End Sub
```

So passing the array to a procedure that then relays it to the `Property Let` seems like a hack to leverage the VBE's rather poor static code analysis in order to get around a compile error that's probably there for a reason.

We know we can't pass an array `ByVal` in VBA. Trying to do so isn't even a *compile error*, it's a *syntax error* and the VBE is quite obviously unhappy with it:

[image: Private Sub IllegalByValArray(ByVal values() As Long)]

This points back to [Rory's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872663/inconsistent-behavior-when-assigning-array-to-a-property-let#comment67036474_39872663) about properties implicitly passing parameters `ByVal`. Here's some proof:

```
Public Property Let Foo(ByRef values As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Foo: " & VarPtr(values)
End Property

Public Sub Test()
    Dim values(0 To 1) As Long
    values(0) = 1
    values(1) = 2

    Dim v As Variant
    v = values

    Debug.Print "Test: " & VarPtr(v)
    IllegalByRefArray v
End Sub

Private Sub IllegalByRefArray(ByRef values As Variant)
    Debug.Print "IllegalByRefArray: " & VarPtr(values)
    Foo = values
End Sub
```

Running the `Test` procedure prints this (or similar) output:

```
Test: 196542488
IllegalByRefArray: 196542488
Foo: 196542352
```

Notice the variable pointer is the same in `Test` and `IllegalByRefArray`, but different in `Foo`, *regardless of the `ByRef` modifier*. If you change the modifier in `IllegalByRefArray` to `ByVal`, you'll get 3 different values instead:

```
Test: 196542488
IllegalByRefArray: 196542384
Foo: 196542336
```

From the accepted answer:

> *If I create a local variable, assign it, then pass it along it seems to work.*

Of course it does; you're now passing a different pointer than the one you received, and VBA tries by several means described above, to discourage you from passing a pointer to an array into a `Property Let` mutator: VBA is trying to tell you in so many ways, that what you're doing isn't something you *should* be doing.

Do things the right way, keep the array encapsulated, and expose an indexed property instead of allowing *the array itself* to be overwritten.

Or make it a public field if you don't care for encapsulation: that property serves literally no purpose.

```
Public Values() As Long
```

There, assign at will.

If you *must* have a `Property Let` mutator for that array, the clean solution is to [pass the array as a `Variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39873577/1188513); yes, this means you need to adjust the rest of your code.

---

### TL;DR:

A `ByRef` modifier on a `Property Let` mutator **makes no sense**: it's a **blatant lie** (it's **not** passed by reference!) and makes your code very confusing. Don't stick a `ByRef` modifier on a `Property Let` value parameter just to satisfy the language syntax which otherwise refuses to pass an array parameter - you're twisting VBA's arm, jeopardizing your users' unsaved work, and making your code tell lies.

Pass a `Variant` instead, or properly encapsulate your array through an indexed property. Anything else is just a dirty stinking hack.

Answer (score 1):

use `Variant`

```
Public Property Let Dummy(v As Variant)

End Property

'rest is the same
```

Comment: Would the brave downvoter ever add some kind note and have both the OP and me know what's wrong with this answer and let me improve it. I can add that, of course, it works.

Comment: I got to this solution after experimenting such a behavior as Rory described. In fact my last trial was to pass the array by reference while this was not permitted. So I decided to try with Variant type instead of an array and it worked. BTW if I fullfilled your question you may want to mark answer as accepted. Thank you