# Why do I get an VBA Run-time error '424' Object Required Error from this code?

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel sheet, I have a cell called `su_callLog`.

My VBA code is:

```
Private Sub su_callLogCopy_Click()
    CopyCell (Range("su_callLog")) 'Error Here
End Sub
Sub CopyCell(cell As Range)
    MsgBox cell.Value
End Sub
```

I'm trying to use the function to process the info in that cell. Even when i try to merely print the contents of the Range, I get the `VBA Run-time error '424' Object Required` error. I'm new to VBA. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

NOTE: `MsgBox (Range("su_callLog"))` produces the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses:

```
CopyCell Range("su_callLog")
```

If you use parentheses, you are forcing that the arguments are taken `ByVal`. And the `Range()` is an object type, which is passed `ByRef`.

[ByVal vs ByRef VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959921/byval-vs-byref-vba)

Comment: That worked!! I'm new to VBA and this is extremely counter intuitive. Could you please tell me why the parenthesis caused the error?!

Comment: @SomenathSinha - Welcome. In general it depends from which programming world are you coming from. If you have coded in C or C++, this is a normal, expected error. If VBA is your first programming language, then this is a bit unexpected and counter intuitive indeed. See the link and the explantion I have added. :)

Answer (score 1):

> As @Vityata correctly pointed oute, you're forcing `ByVal` to be
>   taken, while you need to be passing a reference to a range.

While that much is true and `CopyCell Range("su_callLog")` will produce the desired result, there is one more way to achieve this:

in which you **implicity reference the `Range` correctly** while in parentheses
so in other words, you *(knowingly or unknowingly)* pass the reference properly.

---

```
 CopyCell (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
```

Not only you maintain your desired *(although unnecessary)* braces syntax, but it actually works. Additionally it's a **good VBA coding practice to be using a specific `Sheet` every time you're working with a `Range` object**

So to speak, you sort of kill two birds with one stone here